# Siegel lemma with one contrainst

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, transcendental-number-theory

Les $A=(a_{ij})_{\substack{1\le i\le m\\1\le j\le n}}$ ($n>m$) be a matrix of integers entries. Can one determine a "small" (depending on the size of entries of $A$) solution $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\in \mathbb Z^n$ of the equation $AX=0$ with the constraint $x_n\ne0$. 
I am aware of the articles "Siegel's lemma with additional conditions" and "Integral points of small height outside of a hypersurface" of Lenny Fukshansky. But in these articles, one needs to know the rank of the lattice spanned by the matrix. In pratice, in th proofs in transcendaental theory, one has only estimates for the size of the coefficients of $A$, so one does not have the rank.

Comment: You should be a bit more specific because, as posed, the equation $x_n=0$ may be either in the system itself or derivable from it. So what exactly do you assume (and, if possible, what exactly do you want)?

Comment: I fail to see how the rank of the matrix can be an issue. Just consider linearly independent rows. But the fedja's question is the real problem.

Comment: Abstractly, you have a linear map A from one real vector space to the other, each one with norms and lattices, one lattice mapping to the other. You want a lattice vector of controlled norm in the kernel of A, outside a certain subspace H. If the subspace H does not contain the whole kernel, then this is achieved by Falting's version of Siegel's lemma (or some of its refinements, if you need good bounds).